# swift get bounds of view after constraints are applied

Tags: swift, autolayout

i have a .xib file, that contains a view which i want to use to play a video file. That views has constraints that configure its size and position. Now i need to get those in order to configure my videoplayer:

```
let slide1: OnboardingSlide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("OnboardingSlide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! OnboardingSlide
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Onboarding_01", ofType: "mp4") {
    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    slide1.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: slide1.videoPlayer)
    playerLayer.frame = slide1.videoView.bounds // <-- this does not work

    slide1.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    slide1.videoPlayer?.play()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: slide1.videoPlayer?.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
        slide1.videoPlayer?.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1))
        slide1.videoPlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

but `slide1.videoView.bounds` only contains the rect before the constraints are applied. How can i get the actual size and position?

Comment: Suggestion. Don't use frames, rects or any of the sort. Use actual `NSLayoutConstraint` to setup your views.

Comment: You could override `layoutSubviews()` (of your `OnboardingSlide`) and set the frame of `playerLayer` there (don't forget to call `super`).

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla iOS doesn't support autolayout for `CALayer` (yet)...

Comment: @Alladinian and how do i get the actual size of `videoView` in there? bounds and frame still contain the "default" size here

Comment: The method will be called multiple times, whenever layout is calculated, so the size and position for any subviews (assuming that they are participating in autolayout) will be always current.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force layout machine calculate size and position through calling:

```
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
```

For example:

```
    ...
    slide1.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: slide1.videoPlayer)
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    ...
```

Or just try to catch proper size of the slide1.videoPlayer in `layoutSubviews()`